# Use / Don't use Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I've got an interesting exercise and I tried to use Rolle's Theorem to prove it. Do you think my prove is good or what should I use to prove it?

**Exercise** : For continuous function $f$ we've got : $f(0) = 0$, $f'(x) < 1$ for every $x \in (0,1)$. Show that $f(1) < 1$ .

**Solution** : Rolle's Theorem says : If $f$ is continuous at $[a,b]$ and differentiable at $(a,b)$ and $f(a)=f(b)$ then exists $x \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(x) = 0$.

So i took $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 0$ and I needed to find such $x$ that $f'(x) = 0$, but from **informations** $f'(x) < 1$ for every $x \in (0,1)$, so $f(1) \neq 1$.

But it still doesn't proof that $f(1) < 1$.

Comment: Why did you take $f(1) = 1$? Are you changing the function $f$? $f$ is given to you, so how can you "take $f(1) = 1$"? Besides, if $f(1)$ was in fact $1$, you can't apply Rolle's theorem because the theorem requires $f(0) = f(1)$. You need more practice with the fundamental concept of "applying a theorem" - especially the idea that a theorem only "applies" when its requirements are met.

Comment: My bad, I mean $f(1) = 0$;

Comment: You can't "take $f(1) = 0$ either - $f$ is given.

Comment: I took it to prove that $f(1) \neq 0$ , because Role's Theorem wouldn't be true if $f(1) = 0$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Apply Rolle to $g(x)=f(x)-xf(1)$.

Comment: So I've got $g(0) = 0$ and $g(1) = 0$ but don't know what to do now. Should exists $x \in (0,1)$ such that $g'(x) = 0$.

Comment: OK - now can you compute $g'(x)$, using the definition of $g$?

Comment: Not really sure. Because we don't know if f(1) is differentiable.

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu: $f(1)$ is a constant, how could it not be differentiable?

Comment: But we've got that $f$ is  differentiable at $(0,1)$ so how could I find $f'(1)$?

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu: What are you talking about? You don't need $f'(1)$. Also, if you want your replies to some user to be read by that user, write his name prepended by an `@` sign (like I do in the beginning of this comment).

Answer (score 2):

Let's note that according to Lagrange's theorem for all $a<b$ exists $c\in(a,b)$, such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. This is also true for $0,1$. Therefore, we know that exists $c\in (0,1)$, such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=\frac{f(1)}{1}$. We know that $f'(c)<1$, and therefore, $f(1)=f'(c)<1$.

Comment: That's what I nedded. So I had to use The Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f'(x)<1$ for all $x\in(0,1)$. Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ over $(0,t)$, $0<t<1$, we get $f(t)<t$, so $f(1)<1$.